# Most general definition of limits And Composition

Tags: calculus

According to the composition of limits if $$\lim_{x \to c}g(x)=b$$ and $$\lim_{x \to b}f(x)=L$$ and suppose $g(x) \neq b$ in some neighborhood of $c$ then $$\lim_{x \to c }f(g(x))=L$$. But I want to know that if we go by the most general definition of limit and choose $f(x)$ which is defined at exactly one point in every neighbourhood of $b$ and choose $g(x)$ in such a way that $g(x)$ takes all the values in some neighborhood of $b$ except for those lying in the domain of $f(x)$, then $f(g(x))$ and its limit as $x$ tends to $c$ is not defined.
$$$$ How to explain composition of limits in the most general case of limits?

Comment: How would you construct a domain, such that $f(x)$ is defined at exactly one point in every neighbourhood of b? For what i see this is impossible unless that single point is $b$. What would the domains of both functions be?

Comment: But why this is impossible?

Comment: Let $X$ be the domain of $f$. Given some $\delta >0$ we assume that $\exists! x_\delta \in X: x_\delta \in B_\delta(b)$. Now let $\beta = |x_\delta-b|/2$. By assumption we have that $\exists! x_\beta \in X: x_\beta \in B_\beta(b)$. Notice that $x_\delta\neq x_\beta$. But $x_\beta \in B_\delta(b)$ hence a contradiction.